# Is there something like <c:url> for JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

Is there a taglib in JSF for inserting the proper application context root in any URL I want, just like the `<c:url>` tag in JSP does?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not exactly that, but all JSF components which refer to an URL resource will already automatically include the proper context path and eventually also the `FacesServlet` mapping. For example the [`<h:link>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/link.html):

```html
<h:link value="Link to other page" outcome="otherpage" />
```

which renders something like (assuming that your context path is `/contextname` and your `FacesServlet` is mapped on `*.xhtml`):

```html
<a href="/contextname/otherpage.xhtml">Link to other page</a>
```

You can include request parameters by [`<f:param>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/param.html):

```html
<h:link value="Link to other page" outcome="otherpage">
    <f:param name="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" />
</h:link>
```

which renders something like:

```html
<a href="/contextname/otherpage.xhtml?foo=bar">Link to other page</a>
```

Other link components which also do that are the [`<h:outputStylesheet>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputStylesheet.html), [`<h:outputScript>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputScript.html) and [`<h:graphicImage>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/graphicImage.html) for CSS, JS and images respectively:

```html
<h:outputStylesheet library="default" name="css/foo.css" />
<h:outputScript library="default" name="js/foo.js" />
<h:graphicImage library="default" name="images/foo.png" />
```

which renders something like:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/contextname/javax.faces.resource/css/foo.css.xhtml?ln=default" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/contextname/javax.faces.resource/js/foo.js.xhtml?ln=default"></script>
<img src="/contextname/javax.faces.resource/images/foo.png.xhtml?ln=default" />
```