# Including a js file in jsf adf page

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I want to include a js file in my jsf page. i tried the usual way of doing it but it didnt work.

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/alertMessages.js"></script>
```

I also tried the adf components as below: but there is no af:resource component in my adf lib.

```
<af:document>
  <f:facet name="metaContainer">
    <af:resource source="/mySourceDirectory"/>
  </facet>
  <af:form></af:form>
</af:document>
```

Please let me know how do i include the js file in my page.

Thanks...

Comment: i got the solution for this..

Comment: use this  <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/alertMessages.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative resource URLs (the URLs of `<script>`, `<link>`, `<img>` and `<a>` elements which do not start with scheme `http://` or slash `/`) are relative to the current request URL (as you see in browser address bar).

So if you're for example opening the page by

> http://localhost:8080/contextname/somefolder/page.jsf

then the script file as you have there will actually be downloaded from

> http://localhost:8080/contextname/somefolder/js/alertMessages.js

instead of

> http://localhost:8080/contextname/js/alertMessages.js

You would like to make the URL relative to the domain root instead. So it must become `/contextname/js/alertMessages.js`. You can use `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` to inline the context path dynamically:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/alertMessages.js"></script>
```

Note that the `language` attribute is superfluous. Also please note that for JSF 2.x there are tags available which do that implicitly like `<h:outputScript>`.

#### See also:

- [Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-css-and-images-when-calling-a-servlet-which-forwards-to-a-j/3658735#3658735)
- [Is there something like <c:url> for JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730483/is-there-something-like-curl-for-jsf/7730512#7730512)

Comment: <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/alertMessages.js"></script> did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the af:resource tag for including javascript in ADF Faces pages. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21043_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_resource.html

Comment: Hi Shay, Cant recognise the <source> and no component <af:resource> found in my lib.  this did the trick for me : <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/alertMessages.js"></script>